# Null pointer exception in libGDX when trying to change the position of my Actor in Render

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, libgdx, global-variables

When I try to run this code it gives my a Null pointer exception, only when i call the method of the actor "isPulsado" or "setPosition"

The render method:

```
public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        lienzo.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        shaper1.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        shaper2.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        lienzo.begin();
        shaper1.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        shaper1.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        shaper2.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        shaper2.setColor(0.545f, 0.271f, 0.075f, 1f);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 300; i += 100) {
            for (float j = 0; j <= 300; j += 100) {
                shaper1.box(i, j, 10, 50, 50, 10);
                shaper1.box(i + 50, j + 50, 10, 50, 50, 10);

            }
            for (int j = 0; j <= 300; j += 100) {
                shaper2.box(i, j + 50, 10, 50, 50, 10);
                shaper2.box(i + 50, j, 10, 50, 50, 10);
            }
        }
        shaper1.end();
        shaper2.end();
        lienzo.end();
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        if(reyBlanco.isPulsado())reyBlanco.setPosition(Gdx.input.getX() - 20, -Gdx.input.getY() + 375);
        stage.draw();

    }
```

The class of the actor that I am trying to move

```
public class Rey extends Actor implements InputProcessor {

    private static Sprite sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Rey.png")));
    private float posX = 0;
    private float posY = 0;
    private boolean pulsado = false;

    public boolean isPulsado() {
        return pulsado;
    }
```

I initialized the actor in create method, with her position in the  table

```
public void create() {

        stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        Rey reyBlanco = new Rey(150, 0);
        Reina reinaBlanco = new Reina(200, 0);

        stage.addActor(reyBlanco);
        stage.addActor(reinaBlanco);

        cam = new OrthographicCamera(ancho, alto);

        lienzo = new SpriteBatch();
        shaper1 = new ShapeRenderer();
        shaper2 = new ShapeRenderer();

    }
```

Comment: Have you initialized `reyBlanco` ?

Comment: yes, I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

**NPE** - because you'ven't initialised global variable `reyBlanco`.

Should be

```
reyBlanco = new Rey(150, 0);
```

Instead of

```
Rey reyBlanco = new Rey(150, 0);   // This is local initialization in your code.
```

The above line creates a new variable in the current scope called `reyBlanco` and overrides the global one. The global one is still `null`.